# System of equations for which Cramer's rule is invalid

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, determinant, indeterminate-forms

My teacher told me, that there exists a system of $3$ equations with $3$ unknowns, which isn't indeterminate despite all determinants being equal to $0$. Is it true? How to find this system?

Comment: What do you mean by "all determinants"?

Comment: Using Cramer's rule you can solve system of linear equations using matix determinants. According to Cramer's rule, if all tereminants are equal to 0, the system is indeterminate. My teacher says, that there exist a sytem of 3 equations with 3 unknowns, which despite having all matrix determinants equal to 0 is not indeterminate

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can happen when the system has no solution and there are at least three indeterminates. For instance, for $$\begin{cases} x+y+z=1\\ x+y+z=2\\ x+y+z=3\end{cases}$$ all four determinants that appear in Cramer's rule are zero. This can't quite happen in a $2\times 2$ system (unless the matrix of coefficients is zero) because of Rouché-Capelli and the scarcity of columns.